# Swift List Product

Tags: swift, list-comprehension

Given two lists in Swift:

```
let rows = ["a", "b", "c"]
let cols = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Is it possible to combine them using list comprehension to produce the following:

```
squares = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2", "c3"]
```

Obviously, it can be done using a "for loop" and similar constructs, but I'm specifically for a list comprehension based solution.  I know Swift can do some list comprehension (e.g. let evens = Array(filter(1..<10) { $0 % 2 == 0 }) ) but can't figure out if it can do something similar to the following piece of Haskell:

```
let squares = [ r ++ c | r <- rows, c <- cols]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution (now updated for **Swift 2**):

```
let rows = ["a", "b", "c"]
let cols = ["1", "2", "3"]

let squares = rows.flatMap {
    row in
    cols.map {
        col in
        row + col
    }
}
print(squares)
// [a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3]
```

The inner `map()` maps the `cols` array to an array with the
row number prepended to each entry. The outer `flatMap()` maps
the `rows` array to an array of arrays (one for each row) *and flattens* the result.

Slightly more general, one could define the "product" of two
sequences as an array of tuples (pairs) with all combinations:

```
func product<S : SequenceType, T : SequenceType>(lseq : S, _ rseq : T) -> [(S.Generator.Element, T.Generator.Element)] {
    return lseq.flatMap { left in
        rseq.map { right in
            (left, right)
        }
    }
}
```

and then use it as

```
let squares = product(rows, cols).map(+)
```

Comment: Good answer, though not as succinct as the Haskell version.  I hadn't seen the "flatMap" function before but it does the job nicely.  (I still need to get my head around the functional style of coding.)

Comment: Now the Swift Algorithms package provides an implementation for `product`

Comment: @Shadowrun: Indeed – you should write an answer!