# Swift - avoiding nested forEach closures?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, functional-programming

Let's say I have an array of closures that I want to run on every UITouch.
Here's the code I use:

```
touches.filter { touch in
    return touch.phase == .Ended && touch.tapCount == 1
}.forEach { touch in
    actionsOnTap.forEach { action in
        action(touch)
    }
}
```

It bugs me that there's nested forEach statement, and I guess there's some clean way that can be applied exactly for that case, but I can't think of it. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: The filter part could be: `touches.filter{ $0.phase == .Ended && $0.tapCount == 1}`

Comment: You could probably eliminate the `filter` altogether and just replace it with a `guard` in the `forEach`. That'll reduce the indentation and also increase the efficiency. You could also use `actionsOnTap.forEach{$0(touch)}` in order to keep you from going onto another indentation level.

Comment: To combine each touch with each action you need some kind of nested loop. I don't think there is a built-in library function to create a "product" of two lists, but I may be wrong of course. You can make an utility function for that purpose, as e.g. in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422312/swift-list-product.

Comment: @MartinR If the lists are nested, you can use `flatMap` to create a product of them.

Comment: @CharlesA.: Here you have two separate lists (touches and actions), not a nested list.

Comment: @MartinR I do see that now, not sure how I misread it.

Comment: @MartinR So then it would have to be the `zip` function.  Still probably a worse choice.

Comment: @CharlesA., `zip` does not create a product: items N from list A and B are combined such that you have a sequence like (A[0], B[0]), (A[1], B[1]), etc.

Comment: Yeah, I deleted my answer after re-reading the docs.  What he's got already seems like it is probably the best choice.

Comment: If you really really hate the double forEach, the second forEach could be changed into a `.map` instead...  But I'm sure it does the exact same thing...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should definitely eliminate the `filter` from your logic and possibly use a `guard` inside the first loop instead, for the sake of efficiency and conciseness. I also agree with [@Rob's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37445565/2976878) and [@matt's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37445553/2976878) suggestion of using a traditional for loop instead of `forEach` – at least for the first loop.

Although a (maybe even cleaner) alternative is the integrate the touch conditional logic into the `for` loop directly through using the `where` clause, as well as possibly folding your `forEach` into a single line (whichever you find more readable).

I'd write it like this:

```
for touch in touches where touch.phase == .Ended && touch.tapCount == 1 {
    actionsOnTap.forEach{$0(touch)}
}
```

Comment: I forgot about using `where` here. Thanks.

Comment: That's definitely the best solution here. I didn't know we could use "where" statement in loops, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Personally, I *like* the nesting. I would write:

```
for touch in touches {
    if touch.phase == .Ended {
        if touch.tapCount == 1 {
            actionsOnTap.forEach {$0(touch)}
        }
    }
}
```

To me, that's clean and (above all) clear.

Answer (score 6):

This is a good example of why `forEach` is not a universal (or even appropriately common) replacement for `for-in`. This code become shorter (140 chars vs 186 chars) and clearer just using a traditional `for` loop:

```
for touch in touches where touch.phase == .Ended && touch.tapCount == 1 {    
    for action in actionsOnTap {
        action(touch)
    }
}
```

It also doesn't create an extra array copy the way the `filter` does. This isn't a general reason not to use `filter`. `filter` is a very powerful tool that should be used often, but in this case, it's clearer *and* more efficient to use `for`.

*Edited to use @originaluser2's suggestion of `where` rather than `guard`. That probably is better Swift.*

Answer (score 1):

As you have two heterogeneous array types. another solution that avoid the extra iteration that `filter` do is filter yourself the touches you want to check.

```
touches.forEach{
  guard $0.phase == .Ended && $0.tapCount == 1 else { return }

  actions.forEach{ action in
     action($0)
  }
}
```